# Instagram api. How to use on behalf of another user

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I'm working on instagram service. I faced with trouble.
I created application on intagram for developers. Got secret and client ID.
How to work with api on behalf of another user. For exapmle: users sets their login and password to web application. How to post pictures on behalf of provided account credentials? How this logic should be implemented?

Comment: You can't use other people's credentials. You need to send them through the OAuth flow to get an access token, as laid out in the docs.

Comment: so i can to send user to authorization, then grab token, save it and use it after?

Comment: Yes. Read [the docs](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/).